# Angular4 Custom confirmation dialogue modal

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am a newbie in Angular4. I just want to implement a custom confirmation dialogue modal with yes or no button. I have already referred few example . But none of them are suitable for my requirement.

[It is github library which is almost meeting my requirements.](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/ngx-modialog) 
Any way let me write code in imagination (without implementing it) I want to use my custom confirmation dialogue something like this,

```
 // This code wants to open a modal with yes or no button.
 // Here this.confirmationMessage may be service.
 this.confirmationMessage.show("Can you help me ?")
                         .subscribe(yes=>{
                           /**yes logic*/},
                          no=>{
                          /** No logic*/
                          });
```

So that I can use this anywhere.I know that angular4 have rxjs. I can implement it by using Observable concept. I just would like to know that if I implemented this requirement by using observable would it be a good approach?

Which are the topics in angular4 do I need to cover for this requirement ?
 Is there any library that already available for this scenario?

Any help would be appreciated . :).
Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but this question is too broad and off topic. Too broad because nobody can know your exact requirements. And off-topic because question seeking third-party library are not allowed.